# Bootstrap Navbar not working in Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, themes, navbar

I am trying to learn to use Bootstrap to create a navbar for a Wordpress theme.  I just want to make my menu and not use Navwalker.  I used a simple Bootstrap example from W3 schools but it did not work.  Here is the desired navbar.

Desired result:

[image]

Here I have the same code in my header.

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes();?>>
   <head>
      <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
      <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> |
         <?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(); ?>
      </title>
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>" rel="stylesheet">
      <?php wp_head(); ?>  <!-- This adds other information like plugins to the head -->
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="row">
         hello world
      </div>
      </header>
```

This is how my navbar looks

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try enqueueing your files, through your theme's functions rather than adding them to your header.php.

```
// Load main files  
function enqueue_styles_and_scripts() {

   // Bootstrap
   wp_enqueue_style ('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script    ('bootstrap_js',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true );

   // Main files
   wp_enqueue_style ('style_css',   get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_script    ('main_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 1.1, true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles_and_scripts' );
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your bootstrap css is in your theme directory under a css folder try changing the link to:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This is not how scripts should be loaded in a WP theme.

Comment: True but if you look above someone has already suggested enqueueing the stylesheet, which is the preferred and suggested way of doing it, I was offering a fix to the initial method used...